# Visualize datapoints along a circle in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of 100 values which I would like to display like this: each value is represented as a disk, each disk being placed on a large circle. The color or size of the disk represents the value (normalised between 0 and 1).

I must admit that I don't have enough knowledge with matplotlib to start something like that...

Comment: Where on the larger circle should the disks be placed? Dependent on place in array?

Comment: Equally spaced (the large circle should be made large enough so that the disks don't overlap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place them around the circle with a scatter plot, using the value to set the color using:

```
a = np.random.rand (100)
t = np.linspace (0, 2*np.pi, len(a))
x = np.cos (t)
y = np.sin (t)

plt.scatter (x, y, c = a)
plt.show ()
```

you can use `s = a` to change size of the circle depending on value, or `s = 50` to increase the fixed-size of all circles.

[image: circles]

Comment: if you use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` it will look more like a circle.